# Angular2: date pipe using number expression

Tags: angular

I'm using this expresion in order to format a timestamp number to a date format:

```
{{(subscription$ | async)?.currentPeriodEnd | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

I don't quite figure out why the output is `18/01/1970` for a `1494685110` value.

The value should be `2018/04/14`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `1494685110` isn't along enough for a correct date.  Try multiplying it by 1000.  `1494685110 * 1000` as a date equals `Sat May 13 2017 10:18:30` by using `new Date(1494685110 * 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need milliseconds. Value that you have `1494685110` are seconds.

Add three zeroes at the end (multiply it with 1000), and you got it `1494685110000`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong then this is a epoch time. please try this

> `<mydate>{{item.date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</mydate>`

replace `item.date` with your epoch value variable

For reference go through 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html